# Azure AD - Retrieve a On-Prem AD Group Common Name

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I have an application that needs to filter permissions based on their on-prem AD common name.  Couple of notes:

- Azure AD Connect is syncing data between OnPrem AD and Azure
- I am successfully retrieving the logged on user's group information from Azure Graph API into the Web Application.

The problem I'm having is the data returned from Graph API is not what I need or I have not properly configured Azure AD Connect properly.  The Graph API JSON return object for groups is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/groups-operations#GetAGroup).

Here is the Group object returned from Graph API:

```js
{
  "odata.metadata": "https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/$metadata#directoryObjects/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group/@Element",
  "odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group",
  "objectType": "Group",
  "objectId": "b4bda672-1fba-4711-8fb1-5383c40b2c14",
  "deletionTimestamp": null,
  "description": "Marketing Department",
  "dirSyncEnabled": null,
  "displayName": "Marketing",
  "lastDirSyncTime": null,
  "mail": null,
  "mailNickname": "BposMailNickName",
  "mailEnabled": false,
  "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
  "provisioningErrors": [],
  "proxyAddresses": [],
  "securityEnabled": true
}
```

The closest thing I can find is "Display Name" but this is not the Common Name.  An option, one I don't want to use, is make all of the "Display Names" the same as the group CN.

TLDR;
Is a user groups CN accessible through Graph API and if so, how can I get to this data?

-Update: I'm using the Graph API endpoint getObjectsByObjectIds to hit Graph API once I have retrieve all of the Users Group Ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CN is not accessible through Graph API (AAD or Microsoft Graph). If you are looking for a common unique identifier between on-premises and the cloud the you could use the on-premises group SID (in the cloud `onPremisesSecurityIdentifier`). This property is filterable.

The only other option I can think of (if that's not acceptable and you *really* need CN) is to use [directory schema extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-directory-schema-extensions), to extend the group entity with an additional CN property.  Schema extensions are also filterable.  Please also take a look at the latest AD Connect versions, as I believe they offer the ability to create/configure AAD cloud schema extensions and map from on-premises.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks Dan for the information.  We'll update the authorization filter so that we use the SID/onPremisesSecurityIdentifier property.